# Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Error: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Error : Type '{ id?: string | undefined; title?: string | undefined; content?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Post'.
Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
export interface Post{
    id:string;
    title:string;
    content:string;
}
```

```
import { Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Post } from '../post.model';

import { PostsService } from '../posts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-create',
  templateUrl: './post-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-create.component.css']
})
export class PostCreateComponent implements OnInit {

// newPost='No Content'
enteredTitle='' 
  enteredContent=''
private mode='create'
private postId:string 
private post:Post
  // postId: string | null | undefined;

constructor(public postsService:PostsService
  ,public route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((paramMap:ParamMap)=>{
    if(paramMap.has('postId')){
      this.mode='edit'
      this.postId=paramMap.get('postId')
      this.post=this.postsService.getPost(this.postId)
    }else{
      this.mode='create'
      this.postId="null";
    }
  });
}

onAddPost(form:NgForm){ 
  if(form.invalid)
  {
    return
  } 
  console.log((form.value.title,form.value.content));
  this.postsService.addPost(form.value.title,form.value.content)

form.resetForm();

}
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `private postId: string = ''`

Comment: Dou you need this, this.postId="null"; , cant you change it to ="";

Comment: @Grumpy this.postId=''null" can be changed tothis.postId="" but problem is on 
      this.postId=paramMap.get('postId')
      this.post=this.postsService.getPost(this.postId)

Comment: @Emilien No, thats not a solution

Comment: You need to check `if(postId)` before using it

Answer (score 6):

`paramMap.get()` returns `string|null`. Since your variable is strictly of type string, TS is showing the error.
You could either change the type of `postId` to `string|null`.
Or do something like this `this.postId=paramMap.get('postId') || '';`

Comment: I am getting this error on your solution : Type 'String' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  'string' is a primitive, but 'String' is a wrapper object. Prefer using 'string' when possible.

Comment: Can you check the type of postId ? It might be "String" (Wrapper Object). It should be "string" (primitive)

Answer (score -1):

I think paramMap returns a boolean..you need a string. "Returns
boolean: True if the map contains the given parameter, false otherwise."